# Python: Equation graphs smooth but gives 'jagged' output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using python 2.7, interactive notebook.

When I plot this code...

```
plt.xlabel('Frame')
plt.ylabel('Iterations')
x = np.arange(-10000., 10000., 1)
y = (np.rint((-np.sin(x/88)+x*0.0027)*26.2))-5
y = np.clip(y, 0, 200)
plt.axis([0, 1500, -4, 100])
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=0.5, color='g')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I get a nice pretty smooth graph.

Seen here

[image: Smooth graph]

But when I go to apply this to my number of iterations that I am trying to alter smoothly, rounded to the nearest interger using this code:

```
frame_i = 1
nrframes = 1500
for i in xrange(frame_i, nrframes):
    actualiter = (-np.sin(frame_i/88)+frame_i*0.0027)*26.2 #Iteration Bouncy Curve
    actualiter = np.clip(actualiter, 0, 200)
    plt.plot([frame_i],[actualiter], 'ro')
    plt.axis([0, 1500, 0, 100])
    frame_i = frame_i + 1
plt.show()
```

I get a very jagged output seen here

[image: Jagged graph]

Does anyone know why? Some of my other functions when applied to calculate numbers in my code also "seem" to be very "jaggy"

```
y = -(cos(x/10)*0.007)+0.0029
y = -(cos(x/25)*1)
```

Comment: Can you post examples of this output?

Comment: Edited to include outputs :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example `x` is a float, so `(x/88)` yields a float and you have a continuously variable sin function:
`[sin(0.114), sin(0.227), sin(0.341)... etc.]`

In your second, `frame_i` is an int, so `(frame_i/88)` is being performed as integer division, and therefore your sin function has steps:
`[sin(0), sin(0), .... , sin(0), sin(1), sin(1),... etc.]`

Changing to `88` to `88.0` forces float division, and you get a nice smooth sine wave again.

[image]